# How to validate a string has a proper day month and year with moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I know there are similar questions but I haven't seen my specific issue. I want to allow the user to type in a string that goes in the format of day/month/year.

This is the current function I am using:

```
function isDateValid(value) {
  console.log(moment(moment(value), 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
  const bool = moment(moment(value), 'dd/mm/yyyy', true).isValid();
  return bool;
}
```

The issue is the date will be validated if say the value is '0'. I only want it to be valid if there is a day/month/year.

For example '2/2/2' should not be valid but '2/2/2019' should pass.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know whether a date string was successfully converted into a proper date object, you can invoke the isValid() method on the moment instance variable:

```
var aDate   = moment(dateElt.value, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
var isValid = aDate.isValid();
```